# Chaning value in boolean array list

Tags: java

I have to write a program that displays a number of motorbikes, then customer rent a motorbike and this bike is no longer available. Then I have to record the time of renting and when a person is returning it have record returning time and calculate the cost. I'm a noob programmer. If someone could explain in the simple matter how I could finish this. I have written something like this. Thank you for your time.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
byte numBikes = 15;

boolean[] available = new boolean[numBikes];
String [] timeRented = new String [numBikes];
Arrays.fill(available , true);  


System.out.println("The following bikes are avaialable:\n");
for(byte b = 0; b <= numBikes - 1; b++)
    if(available [b]== true){
        System.out.println(" Bike No" + (byte)(b+1));

    }
System.out.print("Enter your bike number you want choose");
byte bikeNo = s.nextByte();

if (available[bikeNo - 1]== true)
    available[bikeNo - 1] = false;

System.out.println("The following bikes are avaialable:\n");
for(byte b = 0; b <= numBikes - 1; b++)
    if(available [b]== true){
        System.out.println(" Bike No" + (byte)(b+1));
    }
```

Comment: This is where a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) would be handy, as you could encapsulate the all the required information into one or two objects, depending on your design.  As it is, you need synchronize information between your two arrays, so that the index of `timeRented` corresponds to the same index of `available`.  Also some methods would make it much simpler to manage

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about POJO I will read about that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample for you I promp the user for the calculated cost because I don't know how you want to calculate cost I don't know your rent but hope you can just change it in letter b choice

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Help
    {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numBikes =15;
        int availableBike=15;
        int bikeFound=0;

        boolean[] available = new boolean[numBikes];
         String[] timeRented = new String [numBikes];
         String[] returningTime = new String[numBikes];
         int[] calculateCost = new int[numBikes];
         Arrays.fill(available,true);
         String choice="";
         do
         {
             System.out.println("What do you want to do zzz to quit?");
             System.out.println("a.rent a bike b. return a bike");
             choice = scan.nextLine();
             if(choice.charAt(0)=='a')
             {
                System.out.println("The following bikes are available:\n");
                for(int b = 0; b <= numBikes - 1; b++)
                    if(available [b]== true)                
                        System.out.println(" Bike No:" + (b+1));
                System.out.println("Enter your bike number you want choose");
                int bikeNo = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();
                if(availableBike>0)
                {
                    if(available[bikeNo-1]==true)
                    {                   
                        available[bikeNo-1]=false;
                        System.out.println("Enter time of renting");
                        timeRented[bikeNo-1]=scan.nextLine();
                        --availableBike;
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("Sorry bike's not available choose another");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Sorry all bikes are not available at this time");
             }
            else if(choice.charAt(0)=='b')
            {
                System.out.println("The following bikes are not available:\n");
                for(int b = 0; b <= numBikes - 1; b++)
                    if(available [b]== false)               
                        System.out.println(" Bike No:" + (b+1));

                System.out.println("Enter bike number you want to return");
                int bikeNo=scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();
                if(available[bikeNo-1]==false)
                {
                    available[bikeNo-1]=true;
                    System.out.println("Enter out time");
                    returningTime[bikeNo-1]=scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter cost total");
                    calculateCost[bikeNo-1]=scan.nextInt();
                    scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Total is:"+calculateCost[bikeNo-1]);
                    calculateCost[bikeNo-1]=0;
                    ++availableBike;
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Sorry error");
            }
         }
         while(!(choice.equals("zzz")));

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I will calculate the time from a method in other class. Do you think is good a idea to record the time in text file?? and when person return, it will read from that file? I don't want to make things to complicated.

Comment: what system are you trying to create?Are you trying to create a system with database or with text file only? It depends on you,since you don't want to make things complicated I suggest store it only in text file because database is also another language

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for helping me out. What I am trying to do is to create a simple system. Customer log in, then it displays the list of bikes that are available, select bike and time get recorded to a text file. After some time he want to return the bike, when he return the time is calculated and cost is deducted from his account.

Comment: if this answers your problems consider accepting it as an answer for future people reference @BloodySandwich